# Can I change a background color of a twitter bootstrap label with jquery?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using [twitter bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) and I'm trying to change the background-color of a label.  I've allowed the user to change the color mappings so I can't simply change them in the style sheet.  My recent attempt is below:

JQuery

```
var f_threshold_color = localStorage.getItem('f_threshold_color');  

if (f_threshold_color) {
    $('.label-important').css('background-color', f_threshold_color);
}
```

The HTML looks like this:

```
....
<td><span class="label label-important">105</span></td>
...
```

The style in twitter-bootstrap.css looks like this:

```
.label-important {
   background-color: #b94a48;
}
.label-important:hover {
   background-color: #953b39;
}
```

Any idea why it's not using the new background color?

Comment: By the looks of it, it should be working. Can you assemble a jsfiddle to illustrate the issue?

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the element to see which css rules are being applied? You might also need to check to make sure the value of `f_threshold_color` is a valid color, otherwise the browser might just ignore it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just change the following line, it works (see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RNPSm/1/)):

```
var f_threshold_color = 'red';
```

Which means there's something wrong when you store the color in the local storage.

Comment: hmm...It's returning color: #214ce6 which seems to be valid.

Comment: See this updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RNPSm/2/

Once again, your code should be working. Do you get any error messages?

Comment: I found the issue...I'm using the load event and needed to make my call after the script had completed.